# Using sole credentials <none> in realm - Jenkins local instance

Tags: jenkins, svn, build, version-control, automated-tests

**I have done the same thing in the local Jenkins instance as well as the Jenkins instance on the server.**

I have an svn repository and I have automated creating the build using Jenkins. But in the local instance I get an error like this after checking out from the svn repository. The server instance does the job without no errors.

---

Started by user Buddhi Vikasitha
Opening connection to `https://myrepolink/`
Checking out svn `https://myrepolink/trunk` into `/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/_multibranch_pipeline_trunk-PPCYQ43527NS7BYXYB4HKNYOD2FN2YMZ45NVYAN2TOP5K3LK5AOA@script` to read `Jenkinsfile`

Updating `https://myrepolink/trunk@107524` at revision 107524
Using sole credentials buddhi/****** in realm `‘<https://myrepolink:443> Company Subversion repository’`

At revision 107524.
No changes for `https://myrepolink/trunk` since the previous build

Running on Jenkins in `/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/_multibranch_pipeline_trunk-PPCYQ43527NS7BYXYB4HKNYOD2FN2YMZ45NVYAN2TOP5K3LK5AOA`

Cleaning local Directory codebase.

Checking out `https://myrepolink/trunk` at revision '2018-01-08T11:29:54.817 +0530'
Using sole credentials `<none>` in realm `‘<https://myrepolink:443> Company Subversion repository’`
ERROR: Subversion checkout has been canceled

Stage 'Unit Test' skipped due to earlier failure(s)

And other tests skipped due to earlier failure(s)

---

Looks like it checks in the svn repository two times. The second time it gives an error, unable to check with credentials in the second time. (Using sole credentials `<none>`) I don't know why it checks two times either. In the server instance it passes the second check with credentials and continues.

(Credentials and svn repository addresses are checked and correct)

**I need to know what causes the local instance to fail the run here.**

Comment: Seems to happen on my colleague's machine also. Server working and local instance not working.

Comment: Is this happening on Linux?

Comment: Yeah it is hapenning on linux! @user3083324

Answer (score 0):

Global credentials are created at Jenkins->Credentials->System. To use it in a job, you need to add it in the source code management section.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't have a look recently but I will try this solution.